# Saving the Selections of a Checkbox

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save the selections of checkboxes when I open the app or go to a different activity, it is a simple program that shows a list of countries and flags that you can set as favorites,  I just cannot see where I've gone wrong here:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] names;
int[] flags;
Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] countryNames, int[] countryFlags, String[] countryDetails) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_item);
    this.names = countryNames;
    this.flags = countryFlags;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("FreshStart", 0);
    boolean shouldBeChecked = sp.getBoolean(names[position], false);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.mFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mViewHolder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mViewHolder.mCheckBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_Box);

    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    mContext.getSharedPreferences("FreshStart",0);
    mViewHolder.mFlag.setImageResource(flags[position]);
    mViewHolder.mName.setText(names[position]);

    mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(names[position]);
    convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(shouldBeChecked);


    mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                buttonView.setSelected(true);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved as Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                buttonView.setSelected(false);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Longer set as Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mFlag;
    TextView mName;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
}




}
```

Its the `if(isChecked)` part where I seem to be struggling the most right now, I know that I need to save the instance state and I've attempted to use the `SharedPreferences` to save but not completely sure how to use it and was hoping for some help in doing so to help understand it some more

Comment: You need SharedPreference.Editor to edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String[] names;
int[] flags;
Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] countryNames, int[] countryFlags, String[] countryDetails) {
super(context, R.layout.listview_item);
this.names = countryNames;
this.flags = countryFlags;
this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    final SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences("FreshStart", 0);
    boolean shouldBeChecked = sp.getBoolean(names[position], false);

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    mViewHolder.mFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mViewHolder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mViewHolder.mCheckBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_Box);

} else {
    mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
mContext.getSharedPreferences("FreshStart",0);
mViewHolder.mFlag.setImageResource(flags[position]);
mViewHolder.mName.setText(names[position]);

mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(names[position]);
convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(shouldBeChecked);


mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sp.edit();
        preferencesEditor.putBoolean("FreshStart", isChecked);
        preferencesEditor.apply();

        buttonView.setSelected(isChecked);
        if (isChecked)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved as Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Longer set as Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});

return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
ImageView mFlag;
TextView mName;
CheckBox mCheckBox;
}




}
```

Comment: thanks, giving me an error on sp.getBoolean and bChecked

Comment: Not Reconised and wanting to create a class from them

Comment: That was a typo. And I edited my answer to make it more clear. Copy paste the entire file. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, still seems like this line is not reconised

 sp.setBoolean(names[position], isChecked);

Comment: its the setBoolean it doesnt like

Comment: hmm, ok, I used getBoolean and it works to a point, until I close the app and reopen it

Comment: Still the same issue, it's not reconising the setBoolean

Comment: I removed the line. Try now

Comment: still the same result

Comment: I forgot the apply(). This should definitely work. Sorry for all these edits. I should have checked thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext); //mContext is your context
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    buttonView.setSelected(true);
                    if (isChecked){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved as Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        editor.putBoolean("some_name",true); //
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Longer set as Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        editor. editor.putBoolean("some_name",false);
                        editor.apply();
                    }

                }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Kind of, it doesn't recognise editor after editor. editor  <- that one

Comment: ok thanks, it recognises it fine, still not saving the selections, it changes my choices when I scroll as well

Answer (score 0):

```
mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getSharedBoolean(context,"my_switch_key",false));
mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { 
         // buttonView.setSelected(true); // No need to setSelected as callback fired after button check status already change.
         storeSharedItem(context,"storeSharedItem",isChecked);
        }
    }
});

/*
 * RCHIVED_SHARED_PREF "String" the Desired preferences file. If a preferences file by this name
 * does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor 
 */
private final static ARCHIVED_SHARED_PREF = "shared_pref"; // use any String to define SharedPreference storage.

public static boolean getSharedBoolean(Context ctx, String key,boolean def) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(ARCHIVED_SHARED_PREF, 0).getBoolean(key, def);
}

public static void storeSharedItem(Context ctx, String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(ARCHIVED_SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: what is ARCHIVED_SHARED_PREF ?

Comment: It's a String to define SharedPreference storage, Check my update & read  description of param `name` from [getSharedPreferences doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int))